# How can I show properly upwards arrow font symbol on every device?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I have a problem with proper displaying upward and downward arrows symbols on Nokia 3 device.

It shows on Nokia 3 like:

[image]

When on other devices(not Nokia, I don't have more Nokia devices) it is showing properly:

[image]

It's not font-dependent, I've changed the font from default to custom, on both of them it's not displaying in the proper way on Nokia.

Example code for showing the symbols:

```
getString(R.string.sort_creation_date) + " \u2191")
getString(R.string.sort_creation_date) + " " + Html.fromHtml("&#x2191;")
getString(R.string.sort_creation_date) + " " + Html.fromHtml("&#8593;")
```

I know I can replace the symbol with an image but it's not a case. Is there any other way to show it properly?

Comment: have you tried `&uarr;`?

Comment: Yes, I have, but still it's not working

Comment: Try, For upward : &#x2191; and for downward : &#x2193;

Comment: For upward it's already in sample code, there are posted 3 possibilities. New one but not working was that what Ashutosh Sagar posted.

Comment: Are you loading the font by code? The xml attribute is for new Android versions, then you just use the unicode for the font

Comment: It's font independent  as I marked in question. On default and on custom font behavior was exactly the same.  Answering your question, I'm using library for applying to the view custom font.